# Allatori removing method below required annotation

Tags: java, annotations, obfuscation

i'm having an issue with Allatori, i'm using the demo and the latest version.
Basically, after obfuscating with Allatori it removes an important method, that my programm requires in order to work.
Actually this is my config.xml, if it matters;

```
-<config>


-<input single-jar="single.jar">

<jar out="YourFriend 0.0.3.jar" in="YourFriend.jar"/>

</input>

<property value="log.xml" name="log-file"/>

</config>
```

I don't really see why. If there's an @EventHandler annotation it disappears with the method. Is there a way to keep annotations with allatori? 
Thank you
Have a good day